# Cargar fichero en matriz cuyos elementos en el fichero estan divididos por comas

Tags: java

No consigo cargar en una matriz de tipo Persona[2][2] los datos de un fichero de texto, los cuales están separados por una coma.
Tengo problemas al recorrer todos los espacios de la matriz en el fichero...
Agradecería mucho su ayuda...

Comment: Por favor, muéstranos cómo estás intentando agregar los datos. Me imagino que ya conviertes tu csv (Valores separados por comas) a un objeto tipo Persona, cierto?

Answer (score 0):

Debes de agregar el código que haz realizado hasta el momento y también cual es el error que te da o en que falla, sin embargo por lo poco que explicas si lo que quieres es separar por comas cada linea de tu fichero puedes utilizar la función split

```
String fooSeparadoPorComas[] = foo.split(",");
```